# How to override IgnorePointer inside child of IgnorePointer?

Tags: flutter

I've used IgnorePointer and everything works fine.

But there some widgets under `IgnorePointer` I want it to be able to react to a pointer.

How can I override the IgnorePointer for only that widget?

```
Stack(
    children: [
        MouseRegion(
            onHover: (_) {
            visibleController.awake();
            },
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                    // This one work
                    print("TAP...");
                },
                child: Container(color: Colors.red),
            ),
        ),
        IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: true,
            child: 
                child: Row(
                   children: [
                       GestureDetector(
                           onTap: () {
                              // This one doesn't work
                              print("Child inside IgnorePointer tapped"),
                          },
                          child: Container(),
                       ),
                       Container(),
                       Container(),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
);
```

Comment: Wrap them with GestureDetector

Comment: @dm_tr Hmm.. All GestureDetector under IgnorePointer still get ignored.

Comment: Can you post a piece of you code ?

Comment: @dm_tr I've add the example.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269190/pass-trough-all-gestures-between-two-widgets-in-stack/65379440#65379440

Comment: You can also wrap one by one other widgets that must consume gesture events except the one you want to apply the gesture on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IgnorePointer stops hit testing; none of its children will receive pointer events. If you want something that appears to be transparent in a stack but still hit tests its children you can use https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_pointer